# Exposing Sharepoint 2013 REST API Get using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

What I'm trying to do (long term) is process list data and have it pop up on a separate page for management consumption. I've successfully used REST APIs in workflows and now I'm trying my hand at using them in Javascript (something I'm a new to).  My code seems to have success in getting the data. My trouble is how to get at the data so I can process it and then display onto a page in Sharepoint.  A simple example would be great to get me started.

My code I've attached is in a CEWP.

Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
    "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Success in getting the data");
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error in getting List");
  }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the data in success function and add to dom

```
success: function(data){
    data = data.d.results; 
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {  
        console.log(value)
        $(body).append(value.title)
    })
}
```